# OLE Graph in VB 6.0

Tags: graph, vb6, oledb, mschart

I am facing problem in my graphing report created in VB 6.0. I am using an OLE object and insert a `MSGraph.Chart.8` to plot a graph. My graph was okay up to MS Office 2010. But when the company upgraded to MS Office 2013, the problem starts. Please see below image for the actual scenario when populating the graph.

[image]

If you can see the picture, every time my program call the `OLE_GRAPH.AppIsRunning = True`, there is a window that pops up.

Any idea regarding this matter?

Thanks and Regards,
Jessie